# Using ARR to expose TFS project portal to internet

Tags: iis-7, rewrite, arr

I have a public facing web server at www.evju.biz serving several pages (it's behind a NAT'ed firewall) I also have another internal server "winttfs" hosting a TFS server.

I have the URL tfs.evju.biz pointing to the www.evju.biz server. I would like the www.evju.biz server to serve the project portal from the wintfs server when someone uses tfs.evju.biz.

I have installed and enabled Application Request Routing cache. Under the www.evju.biz site I have the following rule:

```
        <rule name="tfs" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*tfs.evju.biz(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://wintfs{r:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
```

This rule does not seem to hit at all. Hos should I set it up?

Answer (score 1):

Did you start with the URL Rewrite wizard for reverse proxy?  That will give you the option of enabling the proxy functionality.

After you do that then your rule should look something like this:

Notice that the domain name is in the condition rather than the url.  The url is just for the part after the domain name.  Here's more info on the [URL parts](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2010/04/20/url-parts-available-to-url-rewrite-rules.aspx).